# Сохранение информации в приложении после закрытия pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

У меня есть маленькое приложение, как набросок с помощью которого хочу сделать уже нормальное. Столкнулся с проблемой, в приложении можно получать бонусные пункты на баланс каждые 5 секунд. Но после закрытия и повторного открытия приложения все сбрасывается, баланс и время до получения бонуса.

**Как можно сделать так чтоб все это сохранялось**? Я узнал что что-то надо сравнивать но как именно и как это делать так и не понял.

main1.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import random   

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(515, 588)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 440, 521, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 490, 521, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(60)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ваши пункты:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Не хватает пунктов?"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "КЛИКАЙ"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №1 100 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №2 100 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №3 100 ПУНКТОВ"))

class Ui_MainWindow_PointApp(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(520, 588)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 400, 251, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 521, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(29)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Получить пункты"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Бесплатные пункты"))

class PointApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow_PointApp):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()       
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.parent = parent                                           

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)                      
        self.pressing = False        

        self.bonus_point = 0                      
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updtTime)
        self.testTimeDisplay = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setFixedSize(0.1, 0.1)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setSegmentStyle(QtWidgets.QLCDNumber.Filled)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setDigitCount(8)

        self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addDays(1) 
        self.fl = True
        self.sec = ...
        self.updtTime()
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def onClicked(self):
        if self.fl:


            self.bonus_point = random.uniform(1, 10.5)                

            self.BonusGet()
            self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(1*6 )

            self.fl = False
            self.sec = 0
        else:
            self.flashSplash()

    def updtTime(self):
        currentTime = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.testTimeDisplay.display(currentTime)



        self.sec = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().secsTo(self.dt)
        if self.sec <= 0:
            self.fl = True


    def flashSplash(self):

        self.splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('rry.png').scaled(382, 72, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.splash.move(755, 680)
        self.splash.show()
        self.splash.showMessage(
            '<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Кнопка будет доступна через {} секунд</h2>'.format(self.sec), 
            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)

        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2200, self.splash.close)

    def BonusGet(self):

        self.splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('ggt.png').scaled(382, 72, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.splash.move(755, 680)  # width()
        self.splash.show()
        self.splash.showMessage(


            '<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Вы получили {:.2f} пунктов</h2>'.format(self.bonus_point), 

            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)


        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2200, self.splash.close)

        self.parent.label_2.setText(
            str(round(float(self.parent.label_2.text()) + self.bonus_point, 2)))

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(515, 588)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 440, 521, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 490, 521, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(60)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ваши пункты:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Не хватает пунктов?"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "КЛИКАЙ"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №1 100 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №2 200 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №3 300 ПУНКТОВ"))



class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked1)     
        self.exampleApp_2 = PointApp(self)          

    def onClicked1(self):
            self.exampleApp_2.show()

    def actionClicked(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())
        print(action.data())   

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Там есть модуль с сохранением

Comment: А не можете ли вы точно сказать его название?

Comment: QSettings для кутэ, inifiles для питона. Мне понравился labs.settings, но он для qml

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам просто нужен файлик, например `bonus.ini`, где вы будете сохранять бонусы.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import random 
import os.path                                                          # +++

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(515, 588)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 440, 521, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 490, 521, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(60)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ваши пункты:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Не хватает пунктов?"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "КЛИКАЙ"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №1 100 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №2 100 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №3 100 ПУНКТОВ"))

class Ui_MainWindow_PointApp(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(520, 588)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 400, 251, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 521, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(29)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Получить пункты"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Бесплатные пункты"))

class PointApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow_PointApp):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()       
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.parent = parent                                           

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)                      
        self.pressing = False        

        self.bonus_point = 0                      
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updtTime)
        self.testTimeDisplay = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setFixedSize(0.1, 0.1)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setSegmentStyle(QtWidgets.QLCDNumber.Filled)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setDigitCount(8)

        self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addDays(1) 
        self.fl = True
        self.sec = ...
        self.updtTime()
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def onClicked(self):
        if self.fl:
            self.bonus_point = random.uniform(1, 10.5)                

            self.BonusGet()
            self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(1*6 )

            self.fl = False
            self.sec = 0
        else:
            self.flashSplash()

    def updtTime(self):
        currentTime = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.testTimeDisplay.display(currentTime)



        self.sec = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().secsTo(self.dt)
        if self.sec <= 0:
            self.fl = True


    def flashSplash(self):

        self.splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('rry.png').scaled(382, 72, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.splash.move(755, 680)
        self.splash.show()
        self.splash.showMessage(
            '<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Кнопка будет доступна через {} секунд</h2>'.format(self.sec), 
            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)

        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2200, self.splash.close)

    def BonusGet(self):

        self.splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('ggt.png').scaled(382, 72, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.splash.move(755, 680)  # width()
        self.splash.show()
        self.splash.showMessage(


            '<h2 style="color:white; font: Arial">Вы получили {:.2f} пунктов</h2>'.format(self.bonus_point), 

            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)


        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2200, self.splash.close)

        self.parent.label_2.setText(
            str(round(float(self.parent.label_2.text()) + self.bonus_point, 2)))

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(515, 588)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 440, 521, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 490, 521, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(60)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ваши пункты:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Не хватает пунктов?"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "КЛИКАЙ"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №1 100 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №2 200 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №3 300 ПУНКТОВ"))



class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        if os.path.exists('bonus.ini'):
            with open('bonus.ini', 'r') as f:
                self.bonus = f.read()
        else:
            with open('bonus.ini', 'w') as f:
                self.bonus = '0'        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked1)     
        self.exampleApp_2 = PointApp(self)  

        self.label_2.setText(self.bonus)                            # +++
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 490, 521, 61))     # +++


    def onClicked1(self):
            self.exampleApp_2.show()

    def actionClicked(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())
        print(action.data())  

    def closeEvent(self, event):                                     # +++
        with open('bonus.ini', 'w') as f:
            self.bonus = f.write(self.label_2.text())             

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно ли сделать так, чтоб файл .ini был невидимым и его нельзя было открыть, чтоб пункты никто не накручивал

Comment: @imapw_ Это уже другой вопрос и по-моему на данном форуме можно найти ответ.