# Сохранение значения checkbox после закрытия и изменение заднего фона виджета, который открывается после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, qsettings

я написал код, в котором есть два окна.

В первом окне мы можем видеть        `checkbox` и `кнопку`, которая открывает виджет или же второе окно.
В первом окне при нажатии `checkbox` фон первого окна меняется на красный.

Надо сделать чтобы фон менялся и во втором окне.

Так-же после закрытия приложения состояние галочки слетает.

Как сделать так, что например в приложении я тыкнул на `checkbox` и в нём появилась галочка. Но после закрытия приложения ее состояние слетает. Как его сохранить?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(280, 215)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 215))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 215))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 281, 221))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(74, 255, 195);")
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 120, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 160, 261, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow2"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First window"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Change button color to yellow in mainwindow"))

class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.parent = parent

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.myClose)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.colorchange)

    def colorchange(self):
        self.parent.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")

    def myClose(self):
        self.close()



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(280, 215)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 215))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 215))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(74, 110, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 271, 31))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 281, 221))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(74, 255, 195);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.checkBox.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Second window"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Switch this and second window background to red"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.checkBoxAction)



    def checkBoxAction(self, state):            
        if (QtCore.Qt.Checked == state):
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        else:
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(74, 255, 195);")

    def clicked(self, item):                                  
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.exampleApp = ExampleApp2(self)   

        countLayout = self.gridLayout.count()   
        for it in range(countLayout):             
            w = self.gridLayout.itemAt(0).widget()
            self.gridLayout.removeWidget(w)               
            w.hide()

        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp, 0, 0, 2, 1)   

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(280, 215)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 215))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 215))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 281, 221))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(74, 255, 195);")
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 120, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 160, 261, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow2"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First window"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Change button color to yellow in mainwindow"))


class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.parent = parent

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.myClose)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.colorchange)

    def colorchange(self):
        self.parent.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")

    def myClose(self):
#        self.close()
        self.parent.show()                                               # +++
        self.hide()                                                      # +++


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(280, 215)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 215))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 215))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(74, 110, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 271, 31))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 281, 221))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(74, 255, 195);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.checkBox.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Second window"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Switch this and second window background to red"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.checkBoxAction)

        self.exampleApp = ExampleApp2(self)                                              # +++

    def checkBoxAction(self, state):            
        if (QtCore.Qt.Checked == state):
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
            self.exampleApp.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")               # +++
        else:
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(74, 255, 195);")
            self.exampleApp.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(74, 255, 195);")  # +++

    def onClicked(self):                          # ???, item):  
        self.exampleApp.show()                                                   # +++
        self.hide()                                                              # +++

''' ???   
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.exampleApp = ExampleApp2(self)   
        countLayout = self.gridLayout.count()   
        print(countLayout)
        for it in range(countLayout):             
            w = self.gridLayout.itemAt(0).widget()
            self.gridLayout.removeWidget(w)               
            w.hide()
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp, 0, 0, 2, 1)   
'''


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> я выбрал чтоб фон приложения был красным. Закрыв его и снова открыв галочка с checkbox убирается и фон становиться обратно зеленым. Нужно чтоб все это как-то сохранялось может быть в какой-нибудь .ini файл, но как я не знаю.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(280, 215)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 215))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 215))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 281, 221))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(74, 255, 195);")
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 120, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 160, 261, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow2"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First window"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Change button color to yellow in mainwindow"))


class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.myClose)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.colorchange)

    def colorchange(self):
        self.parent.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")

    def myClose(self):
#        self.close()
        self.parent.show()    
        self.hide()           

    def closeEvent(self, event):                                            # +++
        self.parent.save()                                                  # +++


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(280, 215)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 215))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 215))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(74, 110, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 271, 31))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 281, 221))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(74, 255, 195);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.checkBox.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Second window"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Switch this and second window background to red"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.checkBoxAction)

        self.exampleApp = ExampleApp2(self)

        self.list_settings = []                                                   # +++
        self.load_settings()                                                      # +++

    def checkBoxAction(self, state):  
        if (QtCore.Qt.Checked == state):
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
            self.exampleApp.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")               
        else:
            self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(74, 255, 195);")
            self.exampleApp.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(74, 255, 195);")  

    def onClicked(self):                            
        self.exampleApp.show()                                          

    def closeEvent(self, event):                                                       # +++
        self.save()                                                                    # +++

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
    def save(self):                                                    
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('WindowState', self.saveState())
        temp_h_l = self.checkBox            
        self.list_settings.append({"text":temp_h_l.text(),
                                   "isChecked()":temp_h_l.isChecked()})
        settings.setValue("Central_widget",self.list_settings.copy())

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        cenral = settings.value('Central_widget')
        if cenral is None:
            return 0
        state = settings.value('WindowState')
        if state:
            self.restoreState(state)
        if cenral:
            for d in cenral:
                self.checkBox.setText(d["text"])
                if d["isChecked()"] is True:
                    self.checkBox.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)


CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config_checkBox.ini'                                      

# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: а как сделать сохранение статуса checkbox?

Comment: @imapw_ объясните пожалуйста лучше, что значит `сделать сохранение статуса checkbox?`  Состояние `checkBox` изменяется когда вы ставите галочку или снимаете ее. Зачем вас что-то сохранять ?

Comment: например, я выбрал чтоб фон приложения был красным. Закрыв его и снова открыв галочка с checkbox убирается и фон становиться обратно зеленым. Нужно чтоб все это как-то сохранялось может быть в какой-нибудь .ini файл, но как я не знаю.

Comment: сохрани в ini файл при закрытии, используй qsettings если хочется сохранить в реестре

Comment: @eri  можно минмальный пример этого всего?

Comment: @imapw_  я уже отвечал на похожий вопрос, смотрите здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1077133/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-pyqt5/1077142#1077142

Comment: @S.Nick А как сохранить stylesheet в ini файл?

Comment: @imapw_ я дополнил ответ, пробуйте.

Comment: @S.Nick спасибо, то что нужно!